# Gettext python pyramid utf8

Tags: python, utf-8, pyramid, gettext

I have a project using gettext to translate English to Japanese but.
This is my code .py file
import gettext

```
t=gettext.translation('noname','advbus/locale', languages=['ja'])
_=t.gettext
print _("Hello")
```

and in file .po

```
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "今日は"
```

I compile .po file to .mop file but it doesn't display right 今日は.(utf8)
When i run .py file it run ok. But not right, my mean is it can't display unicode (ä»Šæ—¥ã?¯)
I try to set utf8 for file .mo file. But error

```
  File "C:\env\Scripts\pserve-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.4a1', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 47, in main
    return command.run()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 290, in run
    relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 318, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\paste\deploy\util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\env\advbus\advbus\__init__.py", line 195, in main
    config.scan()
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.4a1-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\__init__.py", line 946, in scan
    ignore=ignore)
  File "C:\env\lib\site-packages\venusian-1.0a7-py2.7.egg\venusian\__init__.py", line 197, in scan
    __import__(modname)
  File "C:\env\advbus\advbus\hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    t=gettext.translation('noname','advbus/locale', languages=['ja'])
  File "C:\env\lib\gettext.py", line 478, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "C:\env\lib\gettext.py", line 180, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "C:\env\lib\gettext.py", line 281, in _parse
    raise IOError(0, 'Bad magic number', filename)
IOError: [Errno 0] Bad magic number: 'advbus/locale\\ja\\LC_MESSAGES\\noname.mo'
```

This is my subscribers.py  file i coppy on the internet

```
    from pyramid.i18n import get_localizer, TranslationStringFactory

def add_renderer_globals(event):
    request = event['request']
    event['_'] = request.translate
    event['localizer'] = request.localizer

tsf = TranslationStringFactory('YOUR_GETTEXT_DOMAIN')

def add_localizer(event):
    request = event.request
    localizer = get_localizer(request)
    def auto_translate(*args, **kwargs):
        return localizer.translate(tsf(*args, **kwargs))
    request.localizer = localizer
    request.translate = auto_translate
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Mac, Linux, or Windows?  What execution environment?  A command-line terminal window?

Comment: If this is going to a browser, make sure the correct charset is set in the HTTP response headers.

Comment: What process do you use to compile your .po files to .mo? Could you show us that, please?

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Bad magic number` from `gettext.py` points to an improperly-formed `.mo` file. Read your own copy of Python's `gettext.py`, or look at [this Apple-hosted copy of `gettext.py`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/gettext.py).

I'm guessing the compiler from .po to .mo isn't working right. Show us your .po compile process, and maybe we can help further.

Comment: Mr Delahunt please help me ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
"Project-Id-Version: adv 0.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-12-01 11:41+0700\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2012-12-01 09:58+0700\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: ja <LL@li.org>\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: Babel 0.9.6\n"

#: advbus/hello.py:5
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "今日は"
```

That is my .po file
And my .mo file
ä»Šæ—¥ã¯
The string is not right
And i try run .py file, it  works but the string same ä»Šæ—¥ã¯
So i set utf-8 for .mo file, the string display on .mo file ok.
But when i run .py file, had error above

Comment: How do you compile your .po file to an .mo file?  Could you please do the compile process, and then edit your question to show us the exact command you use and the exact output that command shows on the command line?

Comment: Thanks for answer ! First i using python setup.py extract_messages

Comment: Then python setup.py init_catalog -l ja

Comment: And i edit .po file #: advbus/hello.py:6
msgid "Hello"
msgstr ""

->>
#: advbus/hello.py:6
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "今日は"

Comment: python setup.py compile_catalog

Comment: I see the .mo file can't display unicode so i edit set utf8 for it

Comment: Count you provide for me some information can i contact with you in the internet to discuss? Skype or Yahoo please

Comment: Iron Hoang, I will help you in this thread, but don't want to start doing personal technical support. That's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Now, did you know that you can edit your original question? Take all the answers you just put into comments attached to this answer, and rewrite them as part of the question. Be sure to show all the commands you type, and all the responses the commands give.

Comment: Thank for answer, i will find another way